# Webpack import behaviour

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am currently moving over to using webpack, and have added this piece of code before the initialization of my app.

```
delete window.IntersectionObserver;

if (!('IntersectionObserver' in window)) {
    console.log(`Load observer`);
    import('/node_modules/intersection-observer/intersection-observer.js');
    console.log(`Loaded`);
}

console.log(`Start`);
```

I delete the `IntersectionObserver` for testing purposes only.

But when I run the code I get the logs like `Load observer -> Loaded -> Start`

But as far as I know, `import` returns a promise, which means is should be async, or is this some different behaviour I am not familiar with?

I was expecting `Load observer -> Start -> Loaded`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for the promise - you should put the second `console.log` inside a `then()` clause like this

```js
delete window.IntersectionObserver;

if (!('IntersectionObserver' in window)) {
    console.log(`Load observer`);
    import('/node_modules/intersection-observer/intersection-observer.js').then(module => console.log(`Loaded`));
}

console.log(`Start`);
```

or use async/await like this

```
(async () =>
{
delete window.IntersectionObserver;

if (!('IntersectionObserver' in window)) {
    console.log(`Load observer`);
    await import('/node_modules/intersection-observer/intersection-observer.js');
    console.log(`Loaded`);
}

console.log(`Start`);
})();
```